# Lowest eigenvalues of a matrix with divergent entries

Tags: matrix, sparse-matrix

In high energy physics we oftentimes encounter the following problem. For a given parametrized matrix $\{H_{ij}(\Lambda)\}$, we know that in the limit $\Lambda\to\infty$ some of its entries become large:

$$
\text{For some $(i,j)$:  }H_{ij}(\Lambda)\to\infty\text{ as }\Lambda\to\infty.
$$

We also know that in the limit $\Lambda\to\infty$ the lowest eigenvalues in the spectrum of $\{H_{ij}(\Lambda)\}$ — which we are most interested in — tend to converge to particular values (while the larger eigenvalues may potentially diverge).

Have we had access to an "infinite-precision" computer, we could just diagonalize the matrix for increasing values of $\Lambda$ extrapolate to $\Lambda\to\infty$. In reality, this is impractical.

I am wondering if there exist any well-known ways to deal with such a situation, at least for some specific cases (such as divergent elements staying on the diagonal and matrix being sparse).

Comment: Isn't a basis where the entries are not divergent, even though the eigenvalues are not bounded above.

Comment: I'm afraid that finding such a basis may be as hard as finding these eigenvalues.

Comment: Write the eigenvalues as a function of $\Lambda$, and then do extrapolation techniques or Taylor expansion in $1/\Lambda$.

Comment: How can we do this analytically for a matrix of size larger than $4\times 4$? In reality, the matrix is VERY large, even though its entries as analytic functions of $\Lambda$ are known. Doing this numerically this also is not an option as choosing the $\Lambda$-divergent entries to be much larger than others leads to computational issues.

Comment: Is the matrix symmetric? What do you mean by "lowest" otherwise?

Comment: I had Hermitian matrices in mind.

Comment: Do you know something about such matrices?